# How can I place legend relative to text box?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to obtain this:

[image]

But the legend's frame should be perfectly right-aligned with the text box above it. Right now I'm using a poor, manual solution:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5):
  ax.plot([i, 0],label=i)

pad = 0.02
text = ax.text(1-pad, 1-pad, "Some words", bbox=dict(alpha=1),
    transform=ax.transAxes, ha="right", va="top")

# text_height = text.get_bbox_patch().get_height() # doesn't work
text_height=0.05

ax.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1-pad, 1-pad-text_height))
```

So how can I improve and automate this alignment?

Also, it would be nice if I could reasonably set the `pad` parameter automatically.

Comment: I know that's not exactly what you were asking, but do you know `legend()` takes a `title=` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use title parameter:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5):
   ax.plot([i, 0],label=i)

ax.legend(loc="upper right", title='some text')
plt.show()
```